# Getting inconsistent styling (colors) on submit button in WordPress Elementor form

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, submit-button, elementor

This is a minor-but-annoying issue (typical web design) with color styling on my submit button. I'm using the page builder Elementor with OceanWP theme in WordPress. Site URL is http://catalystweb.design (under construction, of course)

The issue is that the colors seems to be "muted" on :active and :focus states. They are being applied, but not with full vibrancy.

I am linking to a [brief screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfMgeqPnFVk) (12 seconds) of the issue, and including the custom CSS I've inserted into that page specifically. FYI the !important flags seem to be required to override some of the theme/builder styles, which makes it even more baffling as to why they are not fully applied in this case.

You'll see that the hover state of the button delivers the colors I've set; but on :focus (using tab) they are muted, and the same on :active (when clicking).

```
button[type=submit]:focus {
  border: 2px solid #63C1FF !important;
  background: #ffffff !important;
  color: #63C1FF !important;
}
button[type=submit]:active {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff !important;
  background: #63C1FF !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Thanks, any insights appreciated!

Comment: Tough to tell without having all of the code, can you share a link to the page with the actual issue?

My feeling is that there's an `opacity` set on :active/:focus with a white background on a parent or pseudo-element, but again it's hard to tell without the source code.

Comment: Thanks for looking Xhynk, just added the URL in the question, and here again: http://catalystweb.design.
It's definitely some kind of opacity, I just have no idea where it's coming from.

Comment: I've searched through the computer stylesheets, found that class .elementor-button had an opacity of .9 applied; so I've targeted that class with an opacity 1 !important. Now the background white comes through 100% on focus, but the text and border, and the active state still have an opacity applied. Mystified. Going to take a break and check back later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stylesheet here: http://catalystweb.design/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/css/frontend.min.css?ver=1.8.8

has an opacity setting on hover:

```
.elementor-button:focus,
.elementor-button:hover,
.elementor-button:visited {
    color: #fff;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

How you want to approach fixing that is up to you, while I don't recommend using `!important;` if you can avoid it:

```
.elementor-button:focus,
.elementor-button:hover,
.elementor-button:visited {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

would work, or a slightly better approach such

```
button.elementor-button:focus,
button.elementor-button:hover,
button.elementor-button:visited {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

would work. You can put this in your main stylesheet or in the Additional CSS are of the customizer, or wherever you've been adding custom CSS.

Comment: Xhynk, thanks so much for giving a full answer. You're correct in what you found - yet it turns out this wasn't the problem. But I did find the problem, and it was - drumroll please - human error [facepalm]. I was looking at the wrong style sheet and applying the wrong color (a different shade of blue). 

I did find that the !important flags were, unfortunately, necessary in the custom CSS. No style changes otherwise. Must be something getting over-ridden by the Elementor plugin.